# inner join with multiple columns return duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a table say `ABC`

```
id smcreatorid smownerid
1  33998       33998
2  33998       3
3  33997       33998
4  33940       33998
5  33997       3
6  1           33997
7  12          33997
8  33998       33940
```

and table `vt_tmp_u33998`

```
id
33997
33998
3
```

I want to fetch all the record whose smownerid is equal to vt_tmp_u33998's id OR creator is **33998**.

My query is

```
SELECT  ABC.smownerid, ABC.smcreatorid FROM ABC
INNER JOIN vt_tmp_u33998 ON vt_tmp_u33998.id = ABC.smownerid or (vt_tmp_u33998.id = ABC.smcreatorid and ABC.smcreatorid = 33998)
```

This Query return Duplicate Records.

```
smcreatorid   smownerid
33998         33998
33998         3
33997         33998
33940         33998
33997         3
33998         3
1             33997
12            33997
33998         33940
```

what I want is without using distinct columns or group by id, fetch all records whose smownerid is equal to **vt_tmp_u33998's id** OR creator is **33998**.

Comment: ***I want to fetch all the record whose owner as well as creator is 33998*** - seems an `AND` logic for me, not `OR`

Answer (score 0):

As you only want records from Table ABC, you don't need the table vt_tmp_u33998. You just need to search table ABC for the results you need. Change your logic to:

```
SELECT ABC.smownerid, ABC.smcreatorid FROM ABC WHERE (ABC.smownerid = 33998 or ABC.smcreatorid = 33998)
```

Comment: Join Is mendatory as per my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT smownerid,smcreatorid 
FROM abc 
JOIN vt_tmp_u33998 
ON vt_tmp_u33998.id = smownerid 
AND smcreatorid =smownerid
AND smownerid=33998
```

Comment: It'll return records whose owner and creator is 33998. but i want all records whose owner OR creator is 33998.

Comment: I want Output as shown in Question except duplicate at "33998         3"

Comment: I didn't get your point in your first comment. I think both are same. But can you please give me any output example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need any data (either for display or for match) from another table, there is no point in using `JOIN`.

Below should suffice your needs to have 33998 as either owner or creater.

```
SELECT ABC.smcreatorid, ABC.smownerid
FROM ABC 
WHERE ABC.smownerid = 33998 
OR ABC.smcreatorid = 33998
```

If 33998 should be both as owner and creater then it would be.

```
SELECT ABC.smcreatorid, ABC.smownerid
FROM ABC 
WHERE ABC.smownerid = 33998 
AND ABC.smcreatorid = 33998
```

Lets say you need records from `ABC` which have either `creator` or `owner` as `33998` and `33998` must be a valid `id` in `vt_tmp_u33998` table then query would be.

```
SELECT ABC.smcreatorid, ABC.smownerid
FROM ABC 
WHERE (ABC.smownerid = 33998 
OR ABC.smcreatorid = 33998)
AND 33998 IN (SELECT id FROM vt_tmp_u33998)
```

similarly when both should be 33998 and should be a valid id from another table then ...

```
SELECT ABC.smcreatorid, ABC.smownerid
FROM ABC 
WHERE ABC.smownerid = 33998 
AND ABC.smcreatorid = 33998
AND 33998 IN (SELECT id FROM vt_tmp_u33998)
```

Comment: there are thousands of records. subquery will slow down process.

Comment: subquery is required only if you need to make sure that the id 33998 is a valid id and exists in vt_tmp_u33998 table. If there is a foreign key constraint on ABC which references id in vt_tmp_u33998 and has on cascade, then you wouldn't need the subquery as foreign key constraint did your work before hand and 33998 being in ABC guarantees that its a valid key and exists in vt_tmp_u33998.

Answer (score 0):

[image: See Below Image]

```
SELECT smownerid,smcreatorid 
FROM abc 
JOIN vt_tmp_u33998 
ON vt_tmp_u33998.id = smownerid 
AND (smownerid=33998 OR smcreatorid=33998)
```

Comment: if we add record for 33997 as smownerid. your query will not return records for 33997. i want records of abc table whose smownerid equal to the vt_tmp_u33998 or smownerid = 33998.

Comment: See above provided result set image.